# Code freezes when trying to set new user password in Active Directory in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

```
var NewUserPC= new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Server, OU, ServiceUserName, ServiceUserPassword);

var user = new UserPrincipal(NewUserPC);

user.GivenName = firstName;
user.Surname = lastName;
user.Name = firstName + " " + lastName;
user.UserPrincipalName = FILN + "@domain.com";
user.SamAccountName = FILN;
user.DisplayName = firstName + " " + lastName;

user.SetPassword("password");
user.Enabled = true;

try
{
    user.Save();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

When I have the `user.SetPassword()` as part of the code and it tries to save user, the code locks up. No exception is caught, can't find any related error in my output window. However, once I comment out that line of code it works just fine.

I've also attempted using LDAP with `DirectoryEntry` to set the password and also using `AccountManagement` to change the password, all with the same locking / freezing result.

I had this working fine in a test environment, but once I moved it to production this issue occurred.

Comment: just a check, you can create a user with the specific password on production? As in, the password meets the password policy rules?

Comment: Yes, using the same admin user credentials, I am able to create an identical user just fine manually.

Comment: And on IIS the apppool runs under an account with enough permission?

Comment: The apppool is using a different account than the admin account I user in the code to access the active directory.

Comment: To add more context, the IIS server is running on one domain and the AD is on another.  This was the case in the test environment as well.

Comment: Check your firewall, probably you need some open ports

Comment: Is there a separate port for just the password methods?  Because everything else works fine.

Comment: It depends, when using Kerberos it is 464 and 88. SMB is used otherwise, see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/09/30/friday-mail-sack-super-slo-mo-edition/. Did you waited long enough? Password operations can take some time is my experience.

Comment: Waited plenty of time.  I'm not thinking it's a firewall issue since the lab worked fine.  Is there any way for me to determine what's going on if my code just locks up and no exceptions are thrown?  I'm using VS 2017.